# Perl DBI no prepare

Tags: perl, odbc, teradata, dbi

I am using Perl (DBI:ODBC) to connect to Teradata. SQL statement being executed is replace procedure statement.
Teradata ODBC driver doesn't allow to prepare REPLACE PROCEDURE throwing exception.
So, instead of prepare + execute I've tried to use do
`$rownum = $con->do("replace procedure ... ");`

The problem is that if replace procedure can not be executed (syntax errors, missing objects) then ODBC driver doesn't generate an error. It simply returns recordset with the list of errors.

So if an error occured during replace procedure, then `$rownum` value will be non zero.
But DBI->do doesn't support return of recordsets.
So, current situation is:

1. I can't use prepare + execute because of unsupported statement by the driver
2. I can't use do, because I can't get error list (however I can identify this error by non-zero rows affected value).

Generally: how to fetch results of the query that can't be prepared?

Comment: Have you tried using odbc_err_handler when connecting? I seem to recall putting a closure in there and that would set an external variable that would give the error. Look in perldoc DBD::ODBC.

Comment: Also would help if you posted the code (remove password and host if any)

Comment: I don't know bout DBI:ODBC, but I wouldn't expect that you can PREPARE a DDL statement. Is there no EXECUTE IMMEDIATE or similar?

Comment: @albe I've tried to use odbc_err_handler but it is not called when procedure failes to be created...

Comment: @alexmac - nothing special in the code: `$con = DBI->connect("dbi:ODBC:$DSN", $user, $pass, {PrintError => 0, RaiseError => 1, AutoCommit => 1} ); my $rownum = $con->do($_[0]);` Here $_[0] has SQL for procedure creation.

Comment: @ikegami Exactly. I can run it with $con->do($SQL) but can't with $sth = $con->prepare($SQL); $sth->execute(); I have also seen this du subroutine and find this strange... Can you please point me to the source code of DBI to see what really do does? Thanks

Comment: @dnoeth Hi Dieter. It is possible to prepare ddl statements (at least create table statements). What do you mean by Execute Immediate? I am running on the client side, not on the server...

Comment: @ikegami I've created custom sub 
 `sub dox {
 my($dbh, $statement, $attr, @params) = @_;
 my $sth = $dbh->prepare($statement, $attr) or return undef;
 $sth->execute(@params) or return undef;
 my $rows = $sth->rows;
 ($rows == 0) ? "0E0" : $rows;
    }`
Strange thing is that it behaves differenetly from the orignal do. When creating procedure do just creates without exceptions by dox throws following: DBD::ODBC::db prepare failed: [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver][Teradata Database
] Syntax error: Invalid  SQL Statement.  (SQL-42000) at Modules/DBTools.pm line
258.

Comment: Ah, I guess the driver can override `do`. Search for "sub do" in DBD::ODBC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Force DBD::ODBC to use SQLExecDirect instead of SQLPrepare/SQLExecute.
[odbc_exec_direct](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD%3a%3aODBC#odbc_exec_direct)

Comment: Yes, thank you. Didn't see your link. Now I have another part of the problem. DBD now says : DBD::ODBC does not yet support binding a named parameter more than once... But I don't have any bindings, it just mixes local procedure variables :Run_Id for example with these named parameters. How to disable this feature? Thanks

Comment: $con->{odbc_ignore_named_placeholders} = 1; does the work. @bhoica thanks a lot for the correct link :). Regards, Dima

Comment: No problem. I should know as I maintain DBD::ODBC.

Comment: Another question - given some SQL statement (we don't know whether it is select or create table) how can one determine whether database returned any results? For example when I create procedure and it goes smoothly then database doesn't return any recordset and when I try to execute fetchrow it generates exception: no select statement currently executing (SQL-HY000). I've created workaround where I use rows affected. If it is 0E0 I am not fetching any data. But how to do it normally? Thanks.

Comment: It's easier to ask new or additional questions as questions rather than comments.